# Corrupted images after uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am having a really weird issue with my image saving method. First, here is the method:

```
        public static void uploadImageToServer(string savePath, HttpPostedFile imageToUpload, bool overwrite)
        {
                byte[] myData = new Byte[imageToUpload.ContentLength];
                imageToUpload.InputStream.Read(myData, 0, imageToUpload.ContentLength);

                FileStream newFile = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create);
                newFile.Write(myData, 0, myData.Length);
                newFile.Close();
}
```

As you can see from the input parameters this method works in conjuction with the FileUpload control. Now I am using this method from two pages which both have a FileUpload control. On one page the image uploads file, on the other page it results in a corrupted file.

I am really at a loss as to why the image is being corrupted. I am using the same image, the same method, and the same input control.

Is there any way I can debug this?

Comment: Why are you not using the SaveAs method? `imageToUpload.SaveAs(savePath);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gonna steal alexn's answer <_<

You are over-complicating it. Just use the built-in [FileUpload::SaveAs(save_path)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx) that is provided for you.

You can use the `Server.MapPath()` method to help you get a dynamic path to your root directory, go from there and append the file name to it.
Not sure why you are getting that error. My best guess is either your `savePath` is broken (or the filename/extension appended to it), or the bytes are not being read/written to perfectly.. Anyway, you should not get that error by using the method I described (considering you don't mess up the file extension :).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this! I had found the original code here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1956/NET-Image-Uploading .